# Python where to mock complexe case

Tags: python, mocking

I have a complexe mocking case where I don't know where to patch in Python

file **supervised_model.py**

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


class SModel:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.model = RandomForestClassifier()
```

file **model.py**

```py
from supervised import SModel


class Model:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.smodel = SModel()
```

file **process.py**

```py
from model import Model


class Processer:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.model = Model()
```

Finally my test case is the following

```py
from process import Processer
from unittest import mock


@mock.patch("what to patch ??? for RandomForestClassifier")
def test_processer(patched_rf):

    patched_rf.return_value.predict_proba.return_value = "foo"

    processer = Processer()
    assert processer.model.smodel.model.predict_proba([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]]) == "foo"
```

I already tryied ...

`@patch("RandomForestClassifier")` and `@patch("smodel.RandomForestClassifier")`

But none of these work,

Thanks by advance

Comment: thanks for your answer but does not work neither

Comment: Why not implement a `TestRandomForestClassifier` with the same interface as `RandomForestClassifier` and put that inside the `SModel` instance in your test?

Comment: In `supervised_model.py` you have `from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier`. That imports the class into `supervised_model`'s namespace. So the patch you need is `@patch('supervised_model.RandomForestClassifier')`.